# React DateTimePicker CSS does not get applied

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, webpack, datetimepicker

I'm trying to use the react DateTimePicker in my project but it does not seem to apply the corrrosponding CSS stylesheets. I've already tried different import methods which I found in different posts but none seems to work. I will try to give you as many information as i may think you could need. I just cannot figure out how to get the css applied...

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
        
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'css-loader',
              options: {
                url: false
              }
            }
          ]
        })
      }
      
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

my imports in my js which dont seem to throw any error:

```
import DateTimePicker from "react-datetime-picker";
import "react-datetime-picker/dist/DateTimePicker.css";
import "react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css";
import "react-clock/dist/Clock.css";
```

my folder structure:
[image]

inside my index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <title>Drivertimes</title>
    {% load static %}
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700&display=swap"
    />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/index.css" %}"
    />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="main">
      <div id="app"></div>
    </div>

    <script src="{% static "frontend/main.js" %}"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

my index.css in which I already tried to use

```
@import "~react-datetime-picker/dist/DateTimePicker.css" :
@import "~react-calendar/dist/Calendar.css";
@import "~react-clock/dist/Clock.css";
```

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#app {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

May not be the right way. But you can copy all css files in your src folder or sub folder next to index html file. Then import from there.

Comment: This is not an answer maybe a comment. According https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges you can leave commtens everywhere.